# Cant delete registry key value after Sleep on Win10

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I need to delete the registry value after the program has been started. So, in order to accomplish that I wrote this small script:

```
On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\14.0"
strValueName = "UserFeedbackOptIn"

wshShell.Run("""%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe""")

wshShell.Sleep 3*60*1000
objRegistry.DeleteValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName
Set wshShell = Nothing
```

The problem is - "wshShell.Sleep". After some investigation I've found that 3 minutes is what works for this task.

**But**, that only works on Win7. When the same script runs on Win10, the key is not getting deleted. And I've no idea why... Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. What happens if you remove `On Error Resume Next`? 2. Does the delete work if you run it on its own? 3. Have you tried adding `... , True)` to the Run command instead of adding a delay?

Comment: 1. No errors appear. 2. Yes, without running the program the script for deleting the value does work. 3. No, I actually have not. I'll give it a try. Thx.

Comment: Sorry - remove the ( ) from the Run call.

Comment: It didn't work..

Comment: 4. Try a shell call to `REG DELETE`. 5. Try doing the delete after reboot with a RunOnce entry in the registry

Comment: Thanks!!! 4. Shell call did a trick. I hate .vbs so much.